# How to display my list<T> elements in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, textbox, listbox

I have two text boxes: name and e-mail. When I click a button they load their text data to a `list<T>`. That data is also displayed in a list box. The list box ends up looking like this:

```
Name: George| E-mail: george@george.com

Name: William | E-mail: william@william.com

Name: Charles | E-mail: charles@charles.com
```

What I want is that when I double-click in a list box item, that item data is displayed in the text boxes that I used to add the data. Something like: I double-click "George" and his name is shown in the text box `Name` and his e-mail is displayed in the text box `E-mail`. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is T?

If you did it right, T is some data-container class with properties for each of the different values, and which overrides ToString() to format the data as you want it presented in the ListBox.

Assuming that's all true, then you can just simply set the ListBox item to the individual T instances. When the user double-clicks on an item, you just cast SelectedItem back to the T instance to retrieve the property values so that they can be copied back to the original input form.

e.g.:

```
class ListBoxItem
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set: }

    public ListBoxItem(string name, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} | E-mail: {1}", Name, Email);
    }
}

(somewhere you have a List<ListBoxItem> and do something like listBox1.Items.AddRange(itemList))

private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;

    // use item.Name and item.Email to initialize TextBox values
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I implemented the CLass as you suggested, but now i got a error when i try to add the text boxes data to my Class, the error is:


"Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication2.frm_cadastro.Cliente' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"


Error here:


clieList.Add(new Cliente()

Comment: What is the "Cliente" class? Given that you seem to want to instantiate one without passing any arguments to the constructor, why doesn't it have a parameterless constructor (i.e. "a constructor that takes 0 arguments")? Note that in my example, the "ListBoxItem" class constructor has parameters...you need to pass the values for "Name" and "Email" to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string foo = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

string[] bar = foo.Split('|');

string name = bar[0].SubString(bar[0].LastIndexOf(':')+2);
string email = bar[1].SubString(bar[1].LastIndexOf(':')+2);

nameTextBox.Text = name;
emailTextBox.Text = email;
```

write something like this in your listbox's double click event.